# "Message":"Invalid object passed in (JSON data formatting issue)

Tags: javascript, json, webmethod

I am trying to send json to my webmethod but its showing below error.

```
{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (17): { \"mappingData
:\"\"[\"Ref No,0\",\"Date,0\",\"Amt,0\",\"Sender Name,0\",\"Sender Add,0\",\"Beneficiary Name,0\",\"Beneficiary
 Add,0\",\"Phone,0\",\"Secret Code,0\",\"Secret Ans,0\",\"Preferred Id,0\"]\"}","StackTrace":"   at System
.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System
.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System
.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit
, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize
(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script
.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services
.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n  
 at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext
 context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context,
 WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}
```

My Javascript code is  :

```
    function tableToJson() { 
        var myArray = [];
        $('.dataRow').each(function(){
            var data= $(this);
            var ColumnAlias= data.find('div.ColumnAlias p').html();
            var TableNames=data.find('div.ddlTableNames select').val();
            var mainData=ColumnAlias+','+TableNames;
            myArray.push(mainData);

        });
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(myArray);
        if (json_text!=null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CorrespondentTemplate.aspx/SaveMappings",
                data: '{ "mappingData:""'+json_text+'"}',
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Please check this line, I don't know whats wrong with it

```
data: '{ "mappingData:""'+json_text+'"}',
```

Comment: please show your html also, `div.ColumnAlias p` and `div.ddlTableNames select` content

Comment: Seriously? You couldn't spot the `""`?

Comment: I spot that my friend but still it was not working

Comment: So why, after you spotted this _obvious_ error, did you leave it in your question??????? Are you trolling us?

Comment: Even after spotted It did not work. I tried many ways okay...... Try it the way you want to do it and let me know only once done from your side. Can't you see the errors we are facing. See the answer from Zee.

Comment: ok move to some other question. Don't waste my time okaysss..

Comment: @Gaurav123: You're the one wasting _our_ time. "The answer from Zee" identifies the exact issue I just commented about, the one you summarily dismissed. Go troll someplace else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78975/discussion-between-gaurav123-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 1):

Quotes are misplaced. Should be

```
data: '{ "mappingData":"'+json_text+'"}',
```

Or you can do this

```
data: JSON.stringify({ mappingData: myArray }),
```

Comment: Still error is there:
{"Message":"Invalid object passed in, \u0027:\u0027 or \u0027}\u0027 expected. (17): { \"mappingData
:\"\"[\"Ref No,0\",\"Date,0\",\"Amt,0\",\"Sender Name,0\",\"Sender Add,0\",\"Beneficiary Name,0\",\"Beneficiary
 Add,0\",\"Phone,0\",\"Secret Code,0\",\"Secret Ans,0\",\"Preferred Id,0\"]\"}","StackTrace":"   at System

Comment: @Gaurav123 I updated. Send it like JSON, why the quotes?

Comment: I tried the updated one.

New Error :

{"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: mappingData.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization

Due to this error I was trying something different

Comment: @Gaurav123 Try passing `myArray` like `"{ 'mappingData':'"+myArray+"'}",`

Comment: You mean to send data as 
data: "{ 'mappingData':'"+myArray+"'}"

Comment: {"Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace"

Answer (score -1):

I tried below way to resolve the above issue.

```
    function tableToJson() { 
        var myArray = [];
        $('.dataRow').each(function(){
            var data= $(this);
            var ColumnAlias= data.find('div.ColumnAlias p').html();
            var TableNames=data.find('div.ddlTableNames select').val();
            var mainData=ColumnAlias+','+TableNames;
            myArray.push(mainData);

        });
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(myArray);
        var jsonFormat={mappingData:json_text};
        var jsonFormatInString=JSON.stringify(jsonFormat);
        if (json_text!=null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "CorrespondentTemplate.aspx/SaveMappings",
                data: jsonFormatInString,
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.d);
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }
```

These three lines done the job for me.

```
        var json_text = JSON.stringify(myArray);
        var jsonFormat={mappingData:json_text};
        var jsonFormatInString=JSON.stringify(jsonFormat);
```

Comment: I missed it I guess ;)

Comment: By the way, thanks for help. I was trying for a long time but after discussion with you I got some Idea, I tried and succeed :)

Comment: Troll.​​​​​​​​​ Is "Zee" a sockpuppet?